# Calling services in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular8

Imagine I have a private property in my component.
Is it possible, to assign a value inside a *then* call to an API and after using it over my component? i.e:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage extends BaseComponent {
    private currentWebDate: string = ""

    ionViewDidEnter(){
       this.getDateAndTime()
    }

    const getDateAndTime = () => {
        this.timeService.getDateAndTime()
           .then((time: Time) => {
                 this.currentWebDate = time.currentDateString
           })
    }

    //and the reuse variable currentWebDate outside subscribe.
}
```

As I tried, the currentWebDate variable is just possible to manipulate inside the *then* call not over the component. Any ideas why?

Comment: Use `getDateTime` into constructor or OnInit method to fill variable immediately after load component

Comment: Note that `.then` would be executed asynchronously, so if you are using it too fast it might not have been updated yet.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you might be missing the (1) injection of the service using the constructor, (2) use getDateAndTime as a method of the class, and (3) public currentWebDate if you what it to be available for the template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage extends BaseComponent {
    public currentWebDate = ""; //<<<(3)

    constructor(private timeService: TimeService){ //<<<(1)
    }

    ionViewDidEnter(){
       this.getDateAndTime()
    }

    private getDateAndTime(): void{ //<<<(2)
        this.timeService.getDateAndTime()
           .then((time: Time) => {
                 this.currentWebDate = time.currentDateString
           })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is old question in programming. You need to understand `asynchronous` and `synchronous` in programming to answer this question.

in my point of view, I do not think "the currentWebDate variable is just possible to manipulate inside the then call not over the component" is RIGHT.

You cannot get the value because before `ionViewDidEnter` your method will not call then the variable have no value. Plus, inside `ionViewDidEnter` you still cannot get value like below:

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
  this.getDateAndTime()
  console.log(this.currentWebDate) // no value
}
```

Because it is about `wait time` issue. at the time you print the value on the lifecycle, the response still not coming.

I suggested you 3 solutions:

1. use rxjs to handle this issue. You can read [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/angular-and-rxjs-patterns-use-reactive-programming-to-compose-and-manage-data-in-angular-apps-2e0c4ce7a39c?source=friends_link&sk=be4b4ec70b1564b9802d1e5afac805a8) to have some idea how to use rxjs to compose and manage your data
2. use state management. I suggested use ngxs that is more easier than ngrx(this one you need to understand redux pattern)
3. [angular resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) in case that you re not familiar with rxjs and state management.